# How many threads per Node.js app?

Tags: node.js

It's often said that Node.js app is single-threaded, however there're total 3 threads resulted from the commands below. What are they?

```
$ node -e 'while (true) {}' &
=> <node_pid>
$ ps huH p <node_pid> | wc -l
=> 3
```

Comment: your javascript code is single-threaded but the underlying engine that runs your javascript code isn't. for example, `node` makes use of the `libuv` library which manages a thread pool. the default is 4 threads; this can be adjusted by setting the environment variable `UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE`. database drivers, etc, may use their own threading strategies separately from libuv. here's good article on the topic: http://www.future-processing.pl/blog/on-problems-with-threads-in-node-js/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The application JavaScript code you write is single-threaded as Node uses callbacks to deal with blocking IO, which are then processed in order by a single event loop. However, all of this is executed by the underlying platform written in C++, the V8 engine, as well as the `libuv` library written in C. These two components do not share the constraints of the event loop, and are able to spawn multiple threads.

Comment: Do all underlying async I/O operations run with other threads than the main app's?

Comment: Most of them use the `libuv` library and its associated Node API, which runs in a separate thread, but they can have their own implementation I believe.

Comment: Do async I/O operations on `libuv` scale out to multi-cores per se, or is the module `cluster` required thereby?

Comment: Whether it does or not is a bit irrelevant, because libuv uses a marginal amount of CPU resources compared to the event loop. And the event loop definitely does not use to multiple cores. Therefore to scale your app, you will need to increase the amount of processes to match the number of CPU cores, which means you'll definitely need to use something like the cluster module or PM2.

Comment: It's often recommended to use Node.js for none CPU-intensive but IO-bound tasks, isn't it?

Comment: All node is, is a single thread that executes JavaScript. If you're making a server using a single thread, and you have a task that uses a lot of CPU, then that task will throttle all work that that server is performing for all of its users. In cases like this, you simply need to offload this task to a separate process, which can ALSO be a Node process, just not the  main web server process. That process can then do the resources intensive task and return the result back to the main process via a callback. Other platforms such as Java and .NET do not have this issue as they are multi threaded.

Comment: That said, Node is actually pretty fast among dynamic languages in terms of pure run time performance, hence it is not a bad choice per se for CPU bound tasks.

Answer (score 1):

Your javascript runs on a single-thread environment while under the hood you have `libuv` which can manage threads. even though `libuv` can create thread pool but nowadays most of the `OS` have threads interfaces available.

In other words `libuv` will use these interfaces prior to thread pools and if they are not available, `libuv` will manage these threads using the thread pool.